# Variable Argument lists with boost?

Tags: c++, boost, variadic-functions

I wanted to write a function with a variable argument list. I want to explore my options. I'm pretty sure I came accross a boost template class that was designed for this purpose, but I can't think of the name of it? Can anyone tell me? or did I dream this up!
Thanks

Comment: You mean variable argument count but one type, or also arbitrary types?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly the library provided, I cant seem to relocate it, I guess it was some sort of improvement over va_list - possibly type safety

Comment: Does your function only need to take arguments of one type or not?

Comment: yes it only needs one type, but variable count.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you only need to accept a variable count of arguments of the same type, taking a container would be the common thing to do. Creation of the container however can be eased using [Boost.Assign](http://boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/assign/doc/index.html):

```
void f(const std::vector<int>& vec) {}
f(boost::assign::list_of(1)(2)(3)(4));
```

Alternatively you can go for operator overloading (e.g. of `operator()` or `operator<<`) yourself, similar to the approach taken by the standard library streams:

```
op() << arg1 << arg2 << arg3;
```

If you really want to provide a type-safe variadic function (without using C++0x features), [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_44_0/libs/preprocessor/) can help. A generic example:

```
#define OUT(z, n, name) << name ## n

#define MAKE_FUNC(z, n, unused)                                     \
    template<class T BOOST_PP_ENUM_TRAILING_PARAMS(n, class T)>     \
    void func(T t BOOST_PP_ENUM_TRAILING_BINARY_PARAMS(n, T, t) ) { \
        std::cout << t BOOST_PP_REPEAT(n, OUT, t) << std::endl;     \
    }

BOOST_PP_REPEAT(9, MAKE_FUNC, ~) // generates func() versions taking 1-10 arguments
func(1, "ab", 'c'); // prints "1abc"
```